# how to assign custom texanomy term to custom post type from frontend

Tags: wordpress

I am creating post from frontend. I want to assign custom texonomy term to  custom post type from front end. I used wp_set_object_terms code but it is replacing custom previous term.
PLease help  me solve out this issue

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to do this, please follow this link 
[wp_set_post_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms)

```
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $tag, $taxonomy );
```